# AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding Encryption Different Result in Java And Python

Tags: python, java, encryption, aes

Similar to this Java AES encryption code, I'm encrypting my data in python, however the results are different.
I gave this some serious days. Would be very grateful for assistance here.

Java

```
public String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String myKey) throws Exception {
        try
        {
            MessageDigest sha = null;
            byte[] key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        }
```

Python

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt(str_to_encrypt, my_key):
    try:
        sha = hashlib.sha1()
        sha.update(my_key.encode('utf-8'))
        key = sha.digest()
        key = key[:16]  # AES-128
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        byte_array = str_to_encrypt.encode("UTF-8")
        padded_data = pad(byte_array, AES.block_size)
        encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
        return base64.b64encode(encrypted_data).decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

def pad(byte_array: bytearray, block_size: int):
    pad_len = block_size - len(byte_array) % block_size
    return byte_array + (bytes([pad_len]) * pad_len)


# Example usage:
my_key = "mySecretKey"
str_to_encrypt = "This is the string to encrypt"
encrypted_string = encrypt(str_to_encrypt, my_key)
print(encrypted_string)
```

java result

```
0xfLbMxzLp0B1v10jgySMuPsNn74Ow55x2R6GUyY9XE=
```

python result

```
jhfQIBB0vFeerfp1LdhZwIW/Bj6VXsPy84YWkci8oPA=
```

Comment: `key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);` is probably returning an array with empty elements to reach the 32 newLength, while in python `key = key[:16]` does not return a string of length 16

Comment: If you print or log the variables each step on both codes you should be able to see at what point they diverge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be the appended zeroes in `key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);`

```
Python Original Key: [109, 121, 83, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116, 75, 101, 121]
Python SHA-1 Digest (key): [170, 243, 150, 73, 152, 47, 173, 4, 165, 19, 82, 143, 200, 228, 115, 234]
Python AES Key: [170, 243, 150, 73, 152, 47, 173, 4, 165, 19, 82, 143, 200, 228, 115, 234]

Python Encrypted Data: [142, 23, 208, 32, 16, 116, 188, 87, 158, 173, 250, 117, 45, 216, 89, 192, 133, 191, 6, 62, 149, 94, 195, 242, 243, 134, 22, 145, 200, 188, 160, 240]



// With key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);
Java Original Key: [109, 121, 83, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116, 75, 101, 121]
Java SHA-1 Digest: [-86, -13, -106, 73, -104, 47, -83, 4, -91, 19, 82, -113, -56, -28, 115, -22, 55, 38, 25, -70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Java SHA-1 Digest (unsigned): 170, 243, 150, 73, 152, 47, 173, 4, 165, 19, 82, 143, 200, 228, 115, 234, 55, 38, 25, 186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
Java Secret Key: [-86, -13, -106, 73, -104, 47, -83, 4, -91, 19, 82, -113, -56, -28, 115, -22, 55, 38, 25, -70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Java Secret Key (unsigned): 170, 243, 150, 73, 152, 47, 173, 4, 165, 19, 82, 143, 200, 228, 115, 234, 55, 38, 25, 186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
Java Encrypted Bytes: [-45, 23, -53, 108, -52, 115, 46, -99, 1, -42, -3, 116, -114, 12, -110, 50, -29, -20, 54, 126, -8, 59, 14, 121, -57, 100, 122, 25, 76, -104, -11, 113]



// With key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
Java Original Key: [109, 121, 83, 101, 99, 114, 101, 116, 75, 101, 121]
Java SHA-1 Digest: [-86, -13, -106, 73, -104, 47, -83, 4, -91, 19, 82, -113, -56, -28, 115, -22]
Java SHA-1 Digest (unsigned): 170, 243, 150, 73, 152, 47, 173, 4, 165, 19, 82, 143, 200, 228, 115, 234, 
Java Secret Key: [-86, -13, -106, 73, -104, 47, -83, 4, -91, 19, 82, -113, -56, -28, 115, -22]
Java Secret Key (unsigned): 170, 243, 150, 73, 152, 47, 173, 4, 165, 19, 82, 143, 200, 228, 115, 234, 
Java Encrypted Bytes: [-114, 23, -48, 32, 16, 116, -68, 87, -98, -83, -6, 117, 45, -40, 89, -64, -123, -65, 6, 62, -107, 94, -61, -14, -13, -122, 22, -111, -56, -68, -96, -16]
Java Encrypted Bytes (unsigned): 142, 23, 208, 32, 16, 116, 188, 87, 158, 173, 250, 117, 45, 216, 89, 192, 133, 191, 6, 62, 149, 94, 195, 242, 243, 134, 22, 145, 200, 188, 160, 240, 
Encrypted Text: jhfQIBB0vFeerfp1LdhZwIW/Bj6VXsPy84YWkci8oPA=
```

Since you can only modify the python code you need to pad the key up to 32 bytes like in the Java code:

```
def encrypt(str_to_encrypt, my_key):
    try:
        sha = hashlib.sha1()
        sha.update(my_key.encode('utf-8'))
        key = sha.digest()
        key = key.ljust(32, b'\0')
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        byte_array = str_to_encrypt.encode("UTF-8")
        padded_data = pad(byte_array, AES.block_size)
        encrypted_data = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
        return base64.b64encode(encrypted_data).decode('utf-8')
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

With `key = key.ljust(32, b'\0')` added we obtain the same output as the Java code `0xfLbMxzLp0B1v10jgySMuPsNn74Ow55x2R6GUyY9XE=`

Comment: Hi Daviid,  Really appreciate the insights but I can not change the Java code. I think I got the gist of it. Thanks.

Comment: @Shubham a bit late but if you can modify the python code the easiest way to  achieve the same result as the java code is to also add padding to reach the 32 bytes it uses as the key, add this `key = key.ljust(32, b'\0')` which will add the byte 0 to the right of the key until it's 32 bytes long.